# Going Back to a Previous Command in Python

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am working on a silly project where I try to print something with the most code possible. What I want it to do is to take an input, split it into a list, and go through every letter on that list. Then it picks a random number from 0 to 26, and sees if the letter it is on matches the letter in a separate list, and if it does, append it to yet another list. It's hard to explain, so here is my current code (not finished):

```
import random 

alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

inserted_words = []

target_word = input('what word do you want printed? (caps only): ')

target_word.split()

class Transform(object):
    def __init__(self, letter, number):
        self.letter = letter
        self.number = number
    def RandomChoose(self, insert):
        let1 = random.randint(0, 26)
        let2 = alphabet[let1]
        if let2 == insert:
            inserted_words.append(insert)
        else:
            RandomChoose()

for x in target_word:
    y = alphabet.index(x)
    x = Transform(x, y)
    x.RandomChoose(x)

print(inserted_words)
```

But there is one problem. Here it is:

```
def RandomChoose(self, insert):
        let1 = random.randint(0, 26)
        let2 = alphabet[let1]
        if let2 == insert:
            inserted_words.append(insert)
        else:
            RandomChoose()
```

I want the code to choose a random letter from my 'alphabet' list, and see if it matches the input. If not, I want it to repeat the code from the beginning. so, if the input is A and the random letter is B, It will repeat, And if the random letter is Q, it repeats again. And so on until it picks A randomly, which will then be appended to 'inserted_words'. I tried recursion but to no avail. If you know what to do, please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def RandomChoose(self, insert):
    letter = None
    while letter != insert:
        letter = random.choice(alphabet)
    inserted_words.append(insert)
```

Also you might as well declare alphabet and and inserted_words as elements of the class and access them from there, because otherwise RandomChoose has no use being a class function.

Furthermore, you're not assigning `target_word.split()` to anything. Try with:

```
target_word = target_word.split()
```

Also not directly relevant to the question, but you can capitalize the input with `target_word.upper()` - that way you won't have to limit input to already capitalized words.